# Convert HH/MM/SS String To A Number Of Minutes

Tags: vb.net

Could Someone Give Me A Code To Convert
A Label With A String Of 01:34:00 
To A Single Number Of Minutes
So 01:34:00 Would Be 94 Mins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a TimeSpan object.

```
Dim ts As TimeSpan 
If TimeSpan.TryParse("01:34:00", ts) Then
 MessageBox.Show(ts.TotalMinutes.ToString)
End If
```